# How to get data from a notepad file and use fft (fast fourier transform on it)

Tags: python, fft

I am a bit of a novice with programming as we are being made to do it in our physics degree. I am using Python 2.

I've been given a txt file with two columns of data, the first few lines look like this:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00 7.335686114232199684e-02 
1.999999999999999909e-07 7.571960558042964973e-01
3.999999999999999819e-07 9.909475704320810374e-01
5.999999999999999728e-07 3.412754086075696081e-01
7.999999999999999638e-07 -5.558766000866324219e-01
9.999999999999999547e-07 -9.810046985453722002e-01
1.199999999999999946e-06 -5.436864816312496629e-01
1.399999999999999937e-06 2.645021165628647641e-01
1.599999999999999928e-06 9.667259209284312371e-01
1.799999999999999919e-06 7.395753817164774091e-01
1.999999999999999909e-06 7.289488801158025555e-02
2.200000000000000112e-06 -7.925906572709742193e-01
2.399999999999999891e-06 -9.727702002847055107e-01
2.599999999999999671e-06 -1.772398644968510018e-01
2.799999999999999873e-06 6.627909312992285029e-01
3.000000000000000076e-06 1.022032186188189362e+00
3.199999999999999855e-06 5.531242183135693935e-01
```

and on it goes for many hundreds of lines.

The question asks:
This week you have been provided with a file which consists of a simulated NMR time domain response following an external impulse. This free induction decay (FID) is characterized by a frequency, an initial amplitude and a decay constant. The data has a single 
oscillation frequency and the second contains a mixture of two frequencies.
Write a program to evaluate the Fast Fourier transform of both signals and plot them
in the frequency domain.

Could someone give me an example of how I might go about doing this? Unfortunately we are not given much guidance in the lab, just some online tutorials and otherwise told to google stuff.

Comment: This can probably solved easily using `numpy` and `scipy`. Try to google for them. If they want you to implement the fft algorithms themselves, then good luck!

Comment: Start by loading the data with numpy.genfromtxt(), then use some FFT function from numpy.fft. That's about it.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html

Answer (score 3):

I'll turn my comment into an answer:

It is actually very easy. Load your data using [numpy.genfromtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) into a numpy array, and then you can choose some form of FFT from [numpy.fft](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html).

As this is your exercise I won't write down exact code but that basically sums it.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your guidance and produced an array from my data file. I then used the basic fft function from 'numpy.fft' and got an array as output. The last part of the exercise is to plot them in the frequency domain. What does this mean? Thanks.

Comment: You can use matplotlib.pyplot.plot() to plot this. It is basically plotting the results you got, and you can see an example at the bottom of this page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html. However, I strongly suggest that you read a little about FFT so you understand what you are doing and what the results mean.

Answer (score 2):

for reading the .txt file, you'll want to do something like this (not the fastest but most clear):

```
column1 = []
column2 = []
infile = open("MyFile.txt", "r")
for l in infile.readlines():
    if l.strip():
        v1 = float(l.split()[0])
        v2 = float(l.split()[1])
        column1.append(v1)
        column2.append(v2)
```

For the fft, look into numpy

Comment: Hi again, thanks. I get an error on the line v1 = float(l.split()[0])

Comment: which says 'list index out of range'

Comment: this probably means that there is a blank line in your file, I made an edit to prevent this

Comment: Thank you, this adjustment worked for separating the data into two separate lists of data.